# Angular Sticky Property Not Working on Table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my code, I have a table with large number of rows. Therefore, I want the headers of the table to be pinned when I scroll down. I added the `sticky` property to my HTML, but that did not work. I even added `sticky`  to the headers one by one. Here is my code and how my table look like. What should I do to fix this?
[image]

- When I scroll down;

[image]
HTML:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid m-4 mt-16">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex class="mt-16 mat-elevation-z2 responsive-grid">
        <form class="w-100-p" #workItemForm>
            <table mat-table matSort #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="w-100-p" style="overflow: auto;">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="UnitType">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngStyle]="{'color': 'black'}" sticky>
                        <b>
                            Birim
                        </b>
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"
                        [ngStyle]="{'color':  row.TotalRequiredQuantity == 0 ? '#046307' : ' #E41B17'}">
                        <div>
                            {{row.UnitType?.Name}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="TotalRequestedQuantity">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngStyle]="{'color': 'black'}" sticky>
                        <b>
                            Planlanan Miktar
                        </b>
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"
                        [ngStyle]="{'color':  row.TotalRequiredQuantity == 0 ? '#046307' : ' #E41B17'}">
                        <div>
                            {{row.TotalRequestedQuantity | number}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="AvailableStockQuantity">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngStyle]="{'color': 'black'}" sticky>
                        <b>
                            Kullanılabilir Stok Miktarı
                        </b>
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"
                        [ngStyle]="{'color':  row.TotalRequiredQuantity == 0 ? '#046307' : ' #E41B17'}">
                        <div>
                            {{row.AvailableStockQuantity | number}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="TotalOrderedQuantity">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngStyle]="{'color': 'black'}" sticky>
                        <b>
                            Sipariş Edilen Miktar
                        </b>
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"
                        [ngStyle]="{'color':  row.TotalRequiredQuantity == 0 ? '#046307' : ' #E41B17'}">
                        <div>
                            {{row.TotalOrderedQuantity | number}}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="TotalRequiredQuantity">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngStyle]="{'color': 'black'}" sticky>
                        <b>
                            Planlanan İhtiyaç Miktarı
                        </b>
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index"
                        [ngStyle]="{'color':  row.TotalRequiredQuantity == 0 ? '#046307' : ' #E41B17'}">
                        <div>
                            <b>
                                {{row.TotalRequiredQuantity | number}}
                            </b>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50, 100]" class="mat-paginator-sticky"></mat-paginator>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the css property position sticky?

you should create a class like:

```
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

and add it to the caption or tr you want to stick to the top

Example:

```
<table>
<tr class="sticky">
<td>
I will stick to the screen when you reach my scroll position</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<p>Some example text..</p>
<h2>Scroll back up again to "remove" the sticky position.</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget (ADD VERY LONG TEXT HERE)</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I added it to the header inside a class tag but, it didn't work

Comment: try to replace your ng-container with a tr tag and put the class="sticky" on the first tr, like in the example above

Comment: That did not work either :/